# How to access the standard output stream (stdout) from Dyalog APL

Tags: stdout, apl, dyalog

There are some possibilities to utilize standard output (stdout) by Dyalog APL language?

Answer (score 2):

## `⎕←`

Assigning to the system variable `⎕` has the side effect of outputting the assigned value to stdout (including a trailing line break):

```
      ⎕←'Hello, World!'
Hello, World!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1EdtE9Q9UnNy8nUUwvOLclIU1f//BwA)

See [APL Wiki: Quad name](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Quad_name#Unusual_behaviour) for more.